# How can I know where an attribute is called? Python

Tags: python, methods

We can call an attribute directly through `object.attribute`, but I guess there are cases that they are called implicit. The code below shows what i believe it's happening:

```
class Test():
    list=[0,1]
    def __init__(self,age):
        print("before __getattribute__")
        self.list[0]=1
        print("after __getattribute__")
    def __getattribute__(self,attribute):
        print("Initializing getattribute")
        return object.__getattribute__(self,attribute)
    def __setattr__(self,attribute,value):
        print("Calling setattr")
test=Test(4)
```

The output is:

```
before __getattribute__
Initializing getattribute
after __getattribute__
```

So `self.list[0]=1` is calling an attribute, since its invoking the `__getatrtibute__`.
What are other cases that this may happen?

Answer (score 1):

[Special Method Names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) in the docs lists all of the methods that get called implicitly by the language syntax.